# JQgrid and Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Can someone point to jqgrid + java web app solution or especially with populating the grid and sending the form back to server. there are several php examples but nothing on java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one example on the web:

- [jqGrid Forum: how-use-jqgrid-in-jsp-server-one-example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/how-use-jqgrid-in-jsp-server-one-example)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use some advanced tools like Spring, Hibernate and Maven here is the good example.

- http://krams915.blogspot.in/2012/01/spring-mvc-31-jqgrid-and-spring-data_1887.html

**EDIT:**
See this, if you want to use plain Servlet and JSP. This is very basic example.

- http://javahunter.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/jqgrid-example/

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `struts2` there's a plugin which includes `jqueryui` and `jqgrid` components.

http://struts2-jquery.googlecode.com/